# Core data to-many filtering

Tags: ios, core-data

I have two entities: `Cluster <-->> Photos`.

I need to select all clusters with photos, where photo id is greater than, ie:

```
Cluster
1 Cluster1
2 Cluster2

Photos
1 Photo1 Cluster1
2 Photo2 Cluster2
3 Photo3 Cluster1
4 Photo4 Cluster2
```

Ie: Get all clusters with photos, where photoId >= 3. I expect to have
Cluster1 - Photo3, Cluster2 - Photo4

Currently I'm trying to create a fetch request for `Cluster` entity with predicate: `ANY photos.id > 393614542`. And it works fine.

Now I'm trying to make `(NOT photos.id IN {393614542, 355088346}) AND photos.id >= 301213165 AND photos.id <= 393614542`, but I have no luck.

It leads to error:`to-many key not allowed here`

Can I perform such query with CoreData?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUBQUERY to test several conditions "simultaneously" for each `photo`:

```
NSPredicate *predciate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(photos, $p, (NOT $p.id IN {393614542, 355088346}) AND $p.id >= 301213165 AND $p.id <= 393614542).@count > 0"];
```

or in Swift:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SUBQUERY(photos, $p, (NOT $p.id IN {393614542, 355088346}) AND $p.id >= 301213165 AND $p.id <= 393614542).@count > 0")
```